# Trying to find whatsapp log

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Hello I've been trying to find the whatsapp.log folder but i can't im making an app and i need the whatsapp.log can anyone tell me whats the exact location and  my phone is rooted

Answer (score 3):

Whatsapp doesn't create a plain `.log` file, all databases are encrypted. These you can find in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/` and the encryption key is in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key`.